# Is there any alternative for endless adapter in android?

Tags: android

I want to implement a loading option whenever the user reach at the last line of the list view. So is there any other option then the endless adapter?

Comment: You can go for `LoadMoreListView` or you can try out `PulltoReferesh` for bottom refresh view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [Dynamic ListView + Loading Footer](http://chrisarriola.wordpress.com/2012/06/15/dynamic-data-with-listview-loading-footer/)

Also there is [PulltoRefresh](https://github.com/shontauro/android-pulltorefresh-and-loadmore) functionality  which you can use for the bottom refresh also.